# how to configure Gerrit trigger to trigger only when master or branches changes excluding (refs/for/*)?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am having troubles how to properly configure Gerrit trigger to only triggers when changes are made to master or other branches (excluding refs/for/rev).

For now I have type:Path, pattern: **/* but it catches any changes (on master/branches and on refs/for/*)

How to construct correct pattern to trigger when refspecs changes only on master and branches but not on refs/for/* ?

Comment: I think you are confused about the "refs/for" term. There's no refs/for/BRANCH. "refs/for" is the way Gerrit uses to know that you're trying to create a review instead of push straight to the branch. Are you trying to trigger the build when the change is effectively integrated to the branch and not when the change is created? See more info here: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html

Comment: yes, I know the Gerrit way, I already have a job which is triggered by new reviews,now I am seeking how to trigger a job when developer is doing `git push origin branch` but not get triggered when `git push origin refs/for/branch`

Answer (score 2):

In Jenkins > Job > Configure > Gerrit Trigger > Trigger on

Add: Change Merged

Do not use any other event like "Patchset Created" or "Draft Published"

Comment: Thanks, what about Gerrit Project -> Pattern, Path set to ** does not work for Change Merged? (job is not triggered)

Comment: It works the same way (Path=**/* should work for every project). Have you submitted some change and the job was not trigged?

Comment: job is triggered with Change Merged and Plain=master, it is not triggered when Path=`**/*` nor `**` nor `**/**` . When changed to trigger on Refs Updated for Path = `**/*` it is also triggered. There is something simple and stupid to be fixed but I don't see it.

Comment: Plain=master?!? Are you talking about project configuration (first type/pattern configuration) or branch configuration (second type/pattern configuration)? For branch configuration Path=** should trigger for every branch.

Comment: I am talking about Branch configuration, project is set to Plain=<project name> . I am aware that branch set to Path=`**` should work but it does not and I don't know why.

Comment: In your first comment you've said "Gerrit Project -> Pattern"... anyway... Path=** should work for any branch, maybe there's some bug, you could try RegExp=.* to see if works.